# How do I tie a table to a value (for example an ID) in SQL?

Tags: sql, attributes

These are actually two questions relating to an online bookstore.

I have a table for customers in SQL, and it has all this customer info, including a customer ID. Then I have a table full of books on sale. Lastly, I have a table for a shopping cart.

Now the shopping cart is going to be a table very similar to the books table, only it will have less items since it'll contain some subset of the book table's contents.

I want the entire cart to be tied to a single customer's ID, and I want every entry in that cart to come directly from the Books table.

How to I go about defining such a table, I mean what statements do I need?

As it is, I'm confused about the issue, because the entire cart table essentially an attribute of a single customer, but I have no idea how to represent that in SQL. I want to be able to look up the cart table using the customer ID, basically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need these four tables:

```
 create table books (book_id int, name varchar(200), author(200));
 create table customers (customer_id int, name varchar(200));
 create table carts (cart_id int, customer_id int);
 create table cart_details (cart_id int, line_number int, book_id int, qty int, price numeric(18,2));
```

In essence, you will store objects like this:

1. Books into `books` table
2. Customers into `customers` table
3. Carts into `carts` and `cart_details` table. `carts` will represent a cart for a certain customer, and `cart_details` will represent cart's content.

Whenever you want to retrieve a cart corresponding to a certain customer you can just do:

```
select * from carts inner join customers using (customer_id);
```

If you also want cart's detail you can do:

```
select * from carts 
inner join cart_details using (cart_id)
inner join customers using (customer_id)
;
```

Note: Tried to write examples in a as general as possible SQL syntax since you didn't provide the RDBMS you are using. Also, left out on purpose all details related to primary and foreign keys so you can understand tables and their attributes first.

Comment: Probably should add a status flag enum to the carts table (in_cart, ordered, billed, shipped, etc.) And 18,2 is overkill for books :) 11,2 is fine for even very expensive books and won't overflow a float.

Comment: @Ariel: true. Just left out a lot of fields for the sake of simplicity. Op is trying fundamentally to understand table/attributes/relationships.

Comment: @Ariel `18,2` may be overkill in US dollars. There are other countries and currencies around.

Comment: @ypercube Anything over `15,*` will overflow a float and requires much more complicated programming. And if you have a currency with such inflation you can use an integer type since they don't bother with fractions (cents).

Comment: @Ariel: I don't understand your overflow comment. How can a numeric(15,2) datatype can overflow? It's not a float

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @ypercube Because you need to get the data from the database and work with it on the frontend, and a float can only hold 15 digits, so anything above that will overflow or loose precision. You can use the numbers as strings I guess, but it's convenient to convert them to floats. (I did *not* say it was impossible - just that it's more complicated.)

Comment: So, don't use floats in the frontend. I don't think it's sound procedure to use numeric in the db and floats in the frontend. Especially when you are dealing with real money.

Comment: @ypercube And when they ask you to show a discount ("17% less than retail")? Or calculate 10% off coupons? Those don't need the exact to the penny data type, so are fine as floats.

Comment: You seem to think that front-ends have only string, integer and float datatypes. But I think we got distracted from the question.

Comment: @ypercube Most in fact do only have those 3 datatypes (again, obviously it's possible, it's just more complicated). But yes, we did get distracted, so user999674 I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could address this by creating a `CustomerCart` table that references the `Customer` and `Book` tables. It could have a format like the following (I'm making this as non-implementation-specific as possible, partly because you haven't indicated what RDBMS you're using):

- Composite primary key consisting of CustomerId + a CartId (allows a Customer to have multiple / saved / historical carts)
- BookId (each record then represents an instance of a book from the catalog being added to a customer's cart)
- Measures, such as Quantity, that relate to the instance of the given book in the given customer's cart

Answer (score 0):

Think of your problem like this... one customer can have many books in their shopping cart, and one book can exist in many customers' shopping carts, so you have a [many-to-many relationship.](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

With this in mind, the way to handle this problem is create a table that tracks the associations between customers and books, including any other information that is relevant.

```
create table shopping_cart (
    customerId int,
    bookId int,
    quantity int,
    etc...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality you want to support with a cart.

The easiest would be to create a cart table with BookID and CustomerID.  However if a customer  or book is ever removed; you will, though cascade deletes if allowed, automatically remove something from someone's cart... or remove all their cart items for a person if the person is removed... do you want that to happen?  If not then you need to keep all book and customer information in the cart.

Secondly, do you want to keep record of everything they've purchased over time in a "Cart" do you want them to be able to checkout with a subset of items in their cart?  Is the life of the cart their visit to the site, or would the items remain months/years after they come back?

The answers to these types of questions determine the appropriate design.